# VBA If Statements Condensed

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Excel 2015, Access 2015

General State:

```
if s=t then
    LD = 0
    Exit Function
end if
```

Current State:

```
If s = t Then: LD = 0: Exit Function
```

Goal:
Is there a way to condense multiple conditional statements into one line without essentially falsifying a return? I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

---

Inspiration: C Code from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

```
for (int j = 0; j < t.Length; j++)
{
    var cost = (s[i] == t[j]) ? 0 : 1;
    v1[j + 1] = Minimum(v1[j] + 1, v0[j + 1] + 1, v0[j] + cost);
}
```

Changed into this in VBA:

```
For j = 0 To Len(t) - 1
    If Mid$(s, i + 1, 1) = Mid$(t, j + 1, 1) Then cost = 0 Else cost = 1
    v1(j + 1) = VBAMin(v1(j) + 1, v0(j + 1) + 1, v0(j) + cost)
Next j
```

Comment: Complex single liners are ___not___ that 'elegant'

Comment: Do you mean besides using something like a `Select Case`?  In some cases, that could provide a more elegant solution.  I also find the conditions can be a little bit more flexible than a normal If-Then conditional statement.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor I generally agree, but I find myself using them for stuff like `Dim v0(): ReDim v0(0 To Len(t))` where I cannot create an array with variable dims in one line but want to condense the functionality into functional group. I guess the coder has the final say on what is **Complex** and I'd argue a two result conditional isn't...

Comment: @Demetri, I use the select function when I'd otherwise be creating several if statements in series; how would a select case benefit when there's only one if statement with multiple reactionary statements

Comment: Well, the short answer is that there is no benefit in that case.  I might have misunderstood your question.  What I do sometimes is use an underscore to link related if then statements in a way that makes sense to me, but the "falsifying" problem, as well as problems with loops, limits it's application.  I'll provide an example of what I do as a "solution", but I don't believe it is really what you're looking for, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 cost = IIf(Mid$(s, I + 1, 1) = Mid$(t, J + 1, 1), 0, 1)
```

Comment: It's this what you were aiming at, if so please help to keep the site updated and acknowledge the answer. Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes do something like the below:

(I know most people would argue it is poor programming)

```
If s = t _
      Then LD = 0:Exit Function _
      Else If a=b _
                Then LD = 1 _
                Else If c=d then LD = 2 Else LD = 3:Exit Function
```

Comment: I updated my original ask with a better example of the direction I'm trying to head. Thanks for your input